# Values from dynamically generated inputs not passing to PHP POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to dynamically create some input fields depending on a value in the database, using a select drop down.

The select works as does the Ajax to show the inputs, however when submitting the data from the dynamically created inputs is missing.

Select value from drop down then get x number of inputs based on db value the jquery code behind this is -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('select').on('change', function() {
var selectValue = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "ext/scripts/get_sizes.php",
  data: {
    selected: selectValue
  },
  success: function (data) {
    $('#values').html(data);
    // Stuff
  },
  error: function (data) {
    // Stuff
  }
 });
});
});
```

This is the code that is returned and that gives me the required number of inputs -

```
$selectedValue = $_POST['selected'];

$sqlQuery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM products_sizes where products_sizes_id = 
'$selectedValue'");
    $string = $sqlQuery->fetch_assoc();
    $str_arr = preg_split ("/\,/", $string['products_sizes_sizes']);

foreach ($str_arr as $id) {
echo '<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="member_values[]" value="'. $id .'"> 
';                                                
            }
```

And finally the code used to update the database -

```
$member_id = Text::input($_POST['member_id']);
$member_sort = Text::input($_POST['member_sort']);
$group_id = Text::input($_POST['group_id']);
$a = implode(',', $_POST['member_values']);

foreach ($languages as $l) {
$member_name = Text::prepare($_POST['member_name'][$l['id']]);


$db->query("INSERT INTO products_sizes_values (products_sizes_values_id, language_id, 
products_sizes_id, products_sizes_values_name, products_sizes_values, psv_sort_order) VALUES (" . 
(int)$member_id . ", " . (int)$l['id'] . ", " . (int)$group_id . ", '" . $db- 
>escape($member_name) . "', '" . $a . "', " . (int)$member_sort . ")");
}
```

As it stands I get the error

> Notice: Undefined index: member_values

Printing the post data gives me the data for the other fields to be updated but not the dynamically created ones.

The dynamic input fields all have the same name and they are merged into an array before being inserted.

Form Code

```
<form name="values" 
action="http://127.0.0.1/fmc/admin/products_sizes.php? 
group_page=1&amp;member_page=1&amp;action=add_size_heading_values" 
method="post"></form>
<input name="formid" type="hidden" 
value="bd1acdc9faa900d509359f07527a565269412e8ee0489470cee47e3fecb1ea80" 
class="form-control">
<tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>
            <select name="group_id" class="custom-select" required="" 
aria-required="true">
              <option name="Mens T-Shirt" value="1">Mens T- 
Shirt</option><option name="Premium Bracelet" value="3">Premium 
Bracelet</option>                   <script>
              
            $(document).ready(function() {
$('select').on('change', function() {
var selectValue = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "ext/scripts/get_sizes.php",
  data: {
    selected: selectValue
  },
  success: function (data) {
    $('#values').html(data);
    // Stuff
  },
  error: function (data) {
    // Stuff
  }
});
});
});
          </script>
                
            </select>
          </td>
          <td><input type="hidden" name="member_id" value="4"><div 
class="input-group mb-1"><div class="input-group-prepend"><span 
class="input-group-text"><img 
src="http://127.0.0.1/fmc/includes/languages/english/images/icon.gif" 
alt="English"></span></div><input type="text" name="member_name[1]" 
required="" aria-required="true" class="form-control"></div></td>
            <td id="values"><input type="text" class="form-control 
input-sm" name="member_values[]" value="Small"> <input type="text" 
class="form-control input-sm" name="member_values[]" value="Medium"> 
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="member_values[]" 
value="Large"> </td>
            
          <td><input type="text" name="member_sort" class="form-control" 
style="width: 60px;"></td>
          <td class="text-right"><button class="btn btn-link" 
type="submit"> <span class="fas fa-save text-success" aria- 
hidden="true"></span> </button></td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: Is `#values` inside the `<form>` that's being submitted to the second script? Please add the HTML.

Comment: @Barmar I have added the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You use member_values[] as the name in the input and then you use member_values  in the $_Post.

```
echo '<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="member_values[]" value="'. $id .'">
 
$a = implode(',', $_POST['member_values']);
```

Could this be the problem?